# How to configure KVM on Ubuntu 22.04 with a trunk port?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm, vlan

I'm setting up a Dell R440, with Ubuntu 22.04, in a trunk port from a Cisco Catalyst Switch. Problem is that only the native vlan traffic is captured in the system.

Port configuration is the following:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/44
 switchport access vlan 201
 switchport trunk native vlan 201
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,201
 switchport mode trunk
!

show interfaces GigabitEthernet 1/0/44 trunk

Port        Mode             Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi1/0/44    on               802.1q         trunking      201

Port        Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi1/0/44    10,201

Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi1/0/44    10,201

Port        Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi1/0/44    10,201
```

This exact configuration sends tagged vlan traffic in other ports, capturable in Debian and a BSD systems just as it should be.

The interface configuration in the server is this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
    inet 192.168.201.20/24 brd 192.168.201.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d294:66ff:feaa:aaaa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f1
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d1:36:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eno1.10@eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.199/24 scope global eno1.10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d294:66ff:feaa:aaaa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: macvtap0@eno1.10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 50:50:50:50:50:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe6e:5932/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As can be seen, there is a vlan interface and a macvtap over it. There's a VM throwing untagged traffic to the vlan interface (from 192.168.10.172). That traffic, as sniffed from the `eno1` interface, is properly tagged in the system:

```
# tcpdump -nvei eno1 vlan 10
tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:38:26.204155 50:50:50:50:50:50 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.4 tell 192.168.10.172, length 28
13:38:27.204132 50:50:50:50:50:50 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.4 tell 192.168.10.172, length 28
13:38:28.222031 50:50:50:50:50:50 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.4 tell 192.168.10.172, length 28
13:38:29.220143 50:50:50:50:50:50 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.4 tell 192.168.10.172, length 28
```

Traffic from the host itself is tagged as well:

```
# tcpdump -nvei eno1 vlan 10
tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:21:21.254534 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.1 tell 192.168.10.199, length 28
14:21:22.278725 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.1 tell 192.168.10.199, length 28
14:21:23.302507 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP (0x0806), Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.10.1 tell 192.168.10.199, length 28
```

Traffic from the native vlan (untagged), from other hosts, can be observed in the main interface (and communication works fine):

```
# tcpdump -nvei eno1 not vlan 10
tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:21:12.669286 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > 00:00:5e:00:01:c9, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 190: (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 61852, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 176)
    192.168.201.20.22 > 172.16.20.10.51758: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4a7a (incorrect -> 0x92f4), seq 967793068:967793192, ack 3024530972, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3219014539 ecr 3285414951], length 124
14:21:12.682517 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab > aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: (tos 0x10, ttl 63, id 31043, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.16.20.10.51758 > 192.168.201.20.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2ef4 (correct), ack 124, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3285414975 ecr 3219014539], length 0
14:21:12.720108 22:22:22:22:22:22 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.201.134 tell 192.168.201.102, length 46
```

This configuration has been applied manually, via:

```
sudo ip link add link eno1 name eno1.10 type vlan id 10
sudo ip link set dev eno1.10 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.10.199/24 dev eno1.10
```

And also via netplan, in other tests, via:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.201.20/24
      gateway4: 192.168.201.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  vlans:
    eno1.10:
      id: 10
      link: eno1
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

Traffic generated from this host, tagged, doesn't reach any other hosts. Also traffic from the other hosts, which is tagged, doesn't reach this host.
There is actually a second server and a second switch (both identical) which are behaving exactly the same (wrong) way, which makes it almost impossible to blame any single hardware piece as defective.

This will be a KVM host for a migration, but the VMs must be able to communicate in the VLANs provided by this trunk (there are many others, this setup is simplified right now for troubleshooting). Any ideas on what is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out nothing was wrong, except the fact that to run the cable to our rack, the datacenter used an additional switch without q in q enabled. This was causing the tagged packets to be dropped in transmission.